# Incorrect Syntax near in After trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have written a Create trigger and it shows me some error on Incorrect Syntax near

### My Code

```
CREATE  TRIGGER [dbo].[News_data] ON [dbo].[News]
AFTER INSERT
AS 
    declare @NID uniqueidentifier;
    select @NID = NEWID();


BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

INSERT INTO [ABC].[News]( 
    @NID,
    [Name], //<-- Incorrect Syntax near [Name]
    [GeoLoc])

    SELECT
    [Name],
    [GeoLoc]
    FROM inserted

END
```

Comment: what is that `@NID` it's not a valid column

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your variable declaration is wrong with column list, if `news` table has primary column for which you are referring to `@NID` then use that column name instead :

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[News] (PK, [Name], [GeoLoc])
    SELECT @NID, [Name], [GeoLoc]
    FROM inserted
```

Comment: Both are same table names with different schemas.When i insert then it insert it with additional value NID guid

Answer (score 2):

Was about to post a sample code, but Yogesh already provided the answer

```
CREATE  TRIGGER [dbo].[Customers_data] ON Customers
INSTEAD OF INSERT AS 
    DECLARE @NID INT = NEWID()
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO Customers( 
        CustomerID,   -- <-- ColumnName instead of its value
        CustomerName, -- <-- Incorrect Syntax near [Name]
        ContactName)
    SELECT
        @NID
        CustomerName,
        ContactName
    FROM inserted
END
```

Something else you might take a look at is the ID. If in one transaction multiple records are inserted, then the inserted will have multiple records with the same 'NewId'. Not sure if that is what you want in your case, but as I suspect that the @NID is the Primary Key, you might want to take a look at that.

Edit: To make sure the trigger still works with a batch-insert. Meaning that multiple records are inserted in one transaction, thus SELECT * FROM inserted will contain multiple records, while you do not wish them to use the same @NID value.

```
CREATE  TRIGGER [dbo].[Customers_data] ON Customers
INSTEAD OF INSERT AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO Customers( 
        CustomerID,   -- <-- ColumnName instead of its value
        CustomerName, 
        ContactName)
    SELECT
        NEWID(),     -- <-- If the 'FROM inserted' contain multiple columns
        CustomerName,
        ContactName
    FROM inserted
END
```

Comment: Yes NID is a GUID type primary key.In here i'm not select that But only Insert newly generated NID

Comment: You might want to wright something like ' INSERT INTO Customers( CustomerID, CustomerName, ContactName) SELECT NEWID() CustomerName, ContactName FROM inserted ' instead. If the 'inserted' table in the trigger contains multiple records (batch-insert), each record will have a different ID if you write your insert statement like this. 

However, a better solution would probably be declaring a default value for the ID column. Just like you can declare something like ' IDENTITY(1,1) ' on a column, you can probably declare ' NEWID() ' as well, although I have not tested that yet.